# Maven add javadoc

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I'm working in a Maven multimodule project and I'm not able to download javadocs for some dependencies. I'll describe my failed attempts:

1. I'm working with Netbeans so the first option was `Right click in Dependencies -> Download Javadocs` and some javadocs were dowoloaded but some other not.
2. Next option was to use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` but the result was the same (some javadocs were still missing). Also I saw that `mvn eclipse` plugin is deprecated
3. Last option was to use `mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc` but the result is the same
4. I configured the `maven-javadoc-plugin` in my `pom.xml` but nothing happens. The configuration is the following:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.10.3</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>attach-javadocs</id>
               <goals>
                   <goal>jar</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

I don't want to use [this option](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/installing-secondary-artifacts.html) because implies a manual downloading. The third option gave me the following output:

```
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    dom4j:dom4j:jar:javadoc:1.6.1:test
[INFO]    org.jboss:jandex:jar:javadoc:1.1.0.Final:test
[INFO]    org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:javadoc:4.3.1.Final:test
[INFO]    org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:javadoc:5.2.4.Final:provided
[INFO]    xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:javadoc:1.0.b2:test
[INFO]    org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:javadoc:4.0.4.Final:test
[INFO]    org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:javadoc:4.3.1.Final:test
[INFO]    antlr:antlr:jar:javadoc:2.7.7:test
[INFO]    javax.activation:activation:jar:javadoc:1.1:provided
```

Any help is appreciated, also if someone tells me that there's no other option but to install the artifacts manually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those artifacts really don't have javadoc attached... It explains why Maven can't download them. Look for [dom4j](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/). There is no `javadoc` on Maven central, only `sources`. The same for [org.jboss:jandex](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/). So you're out of luck here.

Comment: Is there any other repository available?

Comment: That I really don't know... There must be a reason the javadoc wasn't published. You can always [build it from the source](https://github.com/dom4j/dom4j/tree/dom4j_1_6_1)...